# How to remove space between numbers but leave space between names on the same column in a DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to clean a Dataframe in such a way that only cells that contain numbers will not have empty spaces but cells with names remain the same.

```
Author
07 07 34    
08 26 20 
08 26 20 
Tata Smith
Jhon Doe
08 26 22
3409243
```

here is my approach which is failing

```
df.loc[df["Author"].str.isdigit(), "Author"] = df["Author"].strip()
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use regex.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

# Create a sample dataframe
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('Author\n 07 07 34    \n 08 26 20 \n 08 26 20 \n Tata Smith\n Jhon Doe\n 08 26 22\n 3409243'))

# Use regex
mask = df['Author'].str.fullmatch(r'[\d ]*')
df.loc[mask, 'Author'] = df.loc[mask, 'Author'].str.replace(' ', '')

# You can also do the same treatment by the following line
# df['Author'] = df['Author'].apply(lambda s: s.replace(' ', '') if re.match(r'[\d ]*$', s) else s)
```

| Author |
| --- |
| 070734 |
| 082620 |
| 082620 |
| Tata Smith |
| Jhon Doe |
| 082622 |
| 3409243 |

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('two.csv')

# remove spaces on copy
df['Author_clean'] = df['Author'].str.replace(" ","")

# try conversion to numeric if possible
df['Author_clean'] = df['Author_clean'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# fill missing vals with original strings
df['Author_clean'].fillna(df['Author'], inplace=True)

print(df.head(10))
```

**Output:**

```
         Author Author_clean
0  07 07 34          70734.0
1     08 26 20       82620.0
2     08 26 20       82620.0
3    Tata Smith   Tata Smith
4      Jhon Doe     Jhon Doe
5      08 26 22      82622.0
6       3409243    3409243.0
```

Comment: The digits are phone numbers, if you set them to numerics, some of the numbers will lose the first zero which will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't know that these were phone numbers, where the leading 0 matters.